# is there a way to save data in database smaller than 1 byte?

Tags: sql, oracle, bigdata, bit

i have a big data (some TB) that i have to save in a database.

i have some column that can be saved in small numbers (columnA has 20 unique values 1...20 ,columnB has 10 values and etc... ).

is there a way to save this data in a database on only 4-bit,5-bits...(AS NEEDED) ? not 1 byte like tiny int or similar.

if that. what  database engine should i use (for this specific situation)?

Comment: As of Oracle, I think not. If you create a CHARACTER data type column, you can specify either CHAR or BYTE, nothing *smaller* than that.

Comment: No you can't. At least on operating systems I know which can handle 8 bits at minimum as a single unit.

Comment: Why do you need to save it in less than a byte? It's going to be held in at least one byte in the system anyway, regardless of how it looks to you. If you're worried about the size of your data and you have terrabytes of it already, then it would seem there are more effective places to hold the line on size than worrying about a single column that holds 4 bits of data.

Comment: No, you can't store values 1 to 20 in just 4 bits.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure, I'm referring to storage, not the CPU registers handling. Storage on a 64-bit system could still be down to the byte in terms of space usage. It would only be less if more fields in a record were packed in bit fields.

Comment: I don't know about Oracle, but in order to achieve any space saving, your table must contain more than one column that can be stored on less than one byte. Assuming a database engine can store `columnA` on only 5 bits (4 bits can store up to 16 values, not 20 as your `columnA` uses), it could use the remaining 3 bits for another field of the same row, not for a field of a different row. Otherwise `columnA` uses an entire byte whether the database engine can store it on only 5 bits or not.

Comment: My proposal would be to store `RAW` value, i.e. 1 Byte (8 Bit): `UTL_RAW.SUBSTR(UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_BINARY_INTEGER(20), -1)`. Column data type would be `RAW(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to you can pack multiple values into a single byte and use virtual columns and bit operations to extract the individual values:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1fda5/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  value CHAR(1 BYTE),
  five_bits NUMBER(2,0) GENERATED ALWAYS
            AS ( BITAND( ASCII(value), 1+2+4+8+16 ) ) VIRTUAL,
  two_bits  NUMBER(1,0) GENERATED ALWAYS
            AS ( BITAND( ASCII(value), 32+64 ) / 32 ) VIRTUAL,
  one_bit   NUMBER(1,0) GENERATED ALWAYS
            AS ( BITAND( ASCII(value), 128 ) / 128 ) VIRTUAL
);

INSERT INTO test ( value ) VALUES ( CHR( 20 + 2*32 + 0*128 ) );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1fda5/1/0)**:

```
| VALUE | FIVE_BITS | TWO_BITS | ONE_BIT |
|-------|-----------|----------|---------|
|     T |        20 |        2 |       0 |
```

However, there will be a performance overhead to using this workaround and I would suggest that saving a limited number of bytes is probably not worth it.